# What is the meaning of "from" in "the focus to which we attend from them"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

This is a quote from Polanyi and Prosch (1975):

> subsidiaries exist as such by bearing on the focus to which we are attending from them

While I understand the description provided before that quote in [this text](http://corhaethiopia.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Handbook-of-Organizational-Learning.pdf#page=471&zoom=150,75,529), I am unable to grasp the "from" part of the quote:

> Tacit knowing is from–to knowing: we humans know the particulars by relying on our awareness of them for attending to something else. Human awareness has a ‘vectorial’ character: it moves from subsidiary particulars to the focal target

I only ever heard the from in conjunction with "attending" it in the case of guests attending e.g. a party from another city/country

Comment: Your source seems pretty "marginal" English to me, even for such technical / domain-specific subject matter. Are you sure it's not just a bad translation of text which would have been more accessible in the writer's native language?

Comment: A far as I know 'Meaning' was originally written in English. [Here's](https://books.google.de/books?redir_esc=y&hl=de&id=jBx1KTcJ7qIC&q=subsidiaries+exist+as+such#v=snippet&q=subsidiaries%20exist%20as%20such&f=false) the quote in the book.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Polanyi was in fact Hungarian, but his command of written English was impeccable. *Attend **from*** is a term of art within his corpus: We have to 'attend from' the particular rules governing a skill (which in most cases we cannot even articulate) in order to 'attend to' the task at hand, the exercise of that skill. Language is a parade example: most native speakers have only a 'tacit knowledge' of the grammatical rules, but speak the language competently without referring to the rules. They attend **from** the rules **to** the speech act.

Comment: @StoneyB thanks a lot! I know philosophers like to create terms for their works but is there a good, synonymous way to express this idea in easier terms? I only want to briefly bring in the aforementioned text and not delve deeply into Polanyi's philosophy

Comment: @Quanttek Which quotation is it you want to use? and for what?

Comment: @StoneyB I want to talk about when and how tacit knowledge can be articulated. Tsoukas writes that this happens when we are obstructed/disrupted in our practice, which allows us to articulate certain aspects of our old inarticulate background as we shift to a new background. This Polanyi and Porsch quote seemed central to the text (it appears slightly reworded multiple times) because it (seemingly) shows that we can't simply examine the particulars independently w/e because of what they *are*. Tsoukas' added explanation is only one out of 3 aspects that constitute tacit knowledge

Comment: @StoneyB Here's my attempt: "Tsoukas views tacit knowledge as a set of particulars we are subsidiarily aware of, an inarticulate background, as we focus on something else (a practice or action). Those subsidiaries exist by bearing on the focal target “to which we are attending from them”; indirect awareness of them and their meaning are connected to their focal target. Hence, we cannot focus on them in the same context of action where we were subsidiarily aware of them or examine them independently. We can focus on them in a new context of action, a new background, that is brought about by..."

Comment: Hmmm ... I'd do something like this: *Tsoukas adopts Michael Polanyi's notion of 'tacit knowledge', the particulars of which we are only subsidiarily aware as an inarticulate background to our focus on the action we are performing: "subsidiaries exist as such by bearing on the focus **to** which we are attending **from** them" (Polanyi & Polsch 1975; my emphasis). Hence, &c*

Comment: Ohhh. That's a pretty elegant way to solve that! Thanks a lot! However, I'm not entirely sure if it wouldn't confuse the reader when you implicitly take 'tacit knowledge' as the example to explain tacit knowledge. Maybe "a set of particulars" instead of "the particulars" sounds better or would "of which we are subsidiarily aware **of**" be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Subsidiaries exist as such by bearing on the focus to which we are attending from them* is an academic expression. It restates something obvious in a convoluted form.

Think of it this way:

- A **focus** is something that a human can be aware of, e.g. eating a chopped salad in a restaurant.
- A focus may have one or more **subsidiaries**, e.g. from the perspective of the *chef*, the subsidiaries of the chopped salad might be the lettuce, the tomato, the chopping board, the memory of past salad-making, a mental picture of the customer, etc.  From the perspective of the *customer*, the subsidiaries might be the menu, the presence of a salad fork at the table, the sight of the chef through the kitchen window , etc.
- The state of being aware is the state of **attending** to a focus, in the broader sense of a chef attending to the preparation of the salad and the customer attending to its consumption. For both of them, the chopped salad is the focus of their **attention**.
- Awareness moves **from** the subsidiaries to the focus. The focus is the focus because it can be the target of many subsidiaries, just as a city may have one center but many suburbs.

The original expression is attempting to say that subsidiaries are called subsidiaries because attention can move from them to a focus.

Academics often use convoluted language to show off their erudition.  However, as Edgar Rice Burroughs once expressed it in a vastly different context, **erudition is not the same as wisdom** (Jane says this about her father, Professor Archimedes Q. Porter, in the original *Tarzan of the Apes*.)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'm still unsure about the "from". You say that awareness moves from subsidiaries to focus but what constitutes the move? Because I'm only subsidiarily aware (focally unaware) of them, wouldn't a move of the awareness consitute a shift in focus? But that can't be the case as the subsidiarities are tacit and connected to the focal target. Or what is meant here?

Comment: @Quanttek I can't define *awareness*.   However, if you accept the premise that internal mental states can be inferred from external actions, one example could be the action of a poker player in arranging their cards after thinking about the hands that could be formed.  Their attention shifts from the cards to the hand, and its possible value in relation to the hands of other players.  Full house beats a straight, and so on.

Cards exist as subsidiaries by bearing on the poker hand "to which we are attending from them", i.e. we are trying to create the hand *from* the cards.

Comment: The move could be identified by a change in the terms used in self-talk, e.g. from: "Let's see, I've got a three of hearts, a three of spades..." to "Okay, full house, queens over threes, what are my chances here..."  BTW, I don't think that Polanyi  and Prosch offer much of value, since the test of any theory is one's ability to apply it to a set of concrete facts, but if you're stuck with them, so be it.